# Nova Network is deprecated and not supported

Tags: ubuntu, installation, virtual-machine, openstack, devstack

I am currently working on my `mac`, trying to run `DevStack` on my `Ubuntu Xenial OS` being automated by `Vagrant`. After ssh'ing into my VM, I proceed to do a simple `git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack`. This results in the `/devstack` folder being created. After which I proceed to go into that folder and create a `local.conf` with these contents:

```
[[local|localrc]]
DATABASE_PASSWORD=cloud
ADMIN_PASSWORD=cloud
MYSQL_PASSWORD=cloud
RABBIT_PASSWORD=cloud
SERVICE_PASSWORD=cloud
SWIFT_HASH=cloud
SERVICE_TOKEN=tokentoken
LOGDAYS=1
LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log
enable_service s-proxy s-object s-container s-account disable_service n-net
enable_service q-svc
enable_service q-agt
enable_service q-dhcpi
enable_service q-l3
enable_service q-meta
enable_service q-metering
```

Now I proceed to run `stack.sh` by invoking `./stack.sh`. This proceeds pretty smoothly till the point:

```
2017-09-08 03:12:48.345 | Failed to get unit file state for devstack@disable_service.service: No such file or directory
2017-09-08 03:12:48.351 | +functions-common:service_check:1538       for service in '${ENABLED_SERVICES//,/ }'
2017-09-08 03:12:48.358 | +functions-common:service_check:1540       sudo systemctl is-enabled devstack@n-net.service
2017-09-08 03:12:48.366 | enabled
2017-09-08 03:12:48.373 | +functions-common:service_check:1544       sudo systemctl status devstack@n-net.service --no-pager
2017-09-08 03:12:48.382 | ● devstack@n-net.service - Devstack devstack@n-net.service
2017-09-08 03:12:48.382 |    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/devstack@n-net.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
2017-09-08 03:12:48.383 |    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-09-08 03:11:14 UTC; 1min 34s ago
2017-09-08 03:12:48.383 |  Main PID: 5214 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
2017-09-08 03:12:48.383 |
2017-09-08 03:12:48.383 | Sep 08 03:11:10 sharanDevStack systemd[1]: Started Devstack devstack@n-net.service.
2017-09-08 03:12:48.383 | Sep 08 03:11:13 sharanDevStack nova-network[5214]: Config option <oslo_config.cfg.OptGroup object at 0x7f9bd73f2110>.idle_timeout  is deprecated. Use option database.connection_recycle_time instead.
2017-09-08 03:12:48.383 | Sep 08 03:11:13 sharanDevStack nova-network[5214]: ERROR nova.network [-] Nova network is deprecated and not supported except as required for CellsV1 deployments.
2017-09-08 03:12:48.383 | Sep 08 03:11:14 sharanDevStack systemd[1]: devstack@n-net.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2017-09-08 03:12:48.383 | Sep 08 03:11:14 sharanDevStack systemd[1]: devstack@n-net.service: Unit entered failed state.
2017-09-08 03:12:48.383 | Sep 08 03:11:14 sharanDevStack systemd[1]: devstack@n-net.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
2017-09-08 03:12:48.393 | +functions-common:service_check:1          exit_trap
2017-09-08 03:12:48.401 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:493                  local r=3
2017-09-08 03:12:48.411 | ++./stack.sh:exit_trap:494                  jobs -p
2017-09-08 03:12:48.419 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:494                  jobs=
2017-09-08 03:12:48.428 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:497                  [[ -n '' ]]
2017-09-08 03:12:48.435 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:503                  '[' -f /tmp/tmp.qSQpuWS8OM ']'
2017-09-08 03:12:48.446 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:504                  rm /tmp/tmp.qSQpuWS8OM
2017-09-08 03:12:48.454 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:508                  kill_spinner
2017-09-08 03:12:48.464 | +./stack.sh:kill_spinner:407               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
2017-09-08 03:12:48.471 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:510                  [[ 3 -ne 0 ]]
2017-09-08 03:12:48.481 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:511                  echo 'Error on exit'
2017-09-08 03:12:48.481 | Error on exit
2017-09-08 03:12:48.489 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:512                  generate-subunit 1504838624 1744 fail
2017-09-08 03:12:48.882 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:513                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
2017-09-08 03:12:48.889 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:516                  /home/ubuntu/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
2017-09-08 03:12:49.692 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:522                  exit 3
```

What seems to be going wrong here? I think it's the line:

```
2017-09-08 03:12:48.383 | Sep 08 03:11:13 sharanDevStack nova-network[5214]: ERROR nova.network [-] Nova network is deprecated and not supported except as required for CellsV1 deployments.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[local|localrc]]
DATABASE_PASSWORD=cloud
ADMIN_PASSWORD=cloud
MYSQL_PASSWORD=cloud
RABBIT_PASSWORD=cloud
SERVICE_PASSWORD=cloud
SWIFT_HASH=cloud
SERVICE_TOKEN=tokentoken
LOGDAYS=1
LOGFILE=/opt/stack/logs/stack.sh.log
enable_service s-proxy s-object s-container s-account 
disable_service n-net
enable_service q-svc
enable_service q-agt
enable_service q-dhcpi
enable_service q-l3
enable_service q-meta
enable_service q-metering
```

Is the correct script. At this point, this should work.